# Package biblatex Warning: File 'filename.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.9

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use Tex Live and TexWorks/Kile on Windows 7.
I have `biber` 2.10 and `biblatex` 3.10 fully updated (that is what Tex Live Manager 2017 says).

But I can't compile a file created with another latex system as I get the error message:

> `Package biblatex Warning: File 'filename.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.9.`

When I check the file filename.bbl it starts with

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.8 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated as
% required.
%
```

so the file has the version 2.8. This file was created with another latex system.
I would like to make it run on my computer :) What can I do?

Comment: As the beginning lines of the `.bbl` file already tell you, you can simply delete the `.bbl` file and then recompile the `.tex` file on your system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To successfully compile your document, you can sefely delete the `.bbl` file that was created on a different computer with a different version of `biber`. If you then recompile the `.tex` file on your system (using latex, biber, latex, latex),  the required `.bbl` file will be created by `biber` automatically.